# Quotient of a minimal normal subgroup is maximal subgroup provided complement exists?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be group and $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ such that its complement exist in $G$ (say $K$). Is it true that $K$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ ?

Refer [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(group_theory)) for definition of complement.

Comment: This is true when $N$ is abelian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning, spoiler below.**

> Take $G = S_{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers:

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $K$ be a complement to $N$, say $G = NK$.

If $K \leq X \leq G$, then you can show that $X = (X \cap N)K$. Note that $X \cap N$ is normal in $X$, so it is normalized by $K$.

Conversely if $N_0$ is a subgroup of $N$ that is normalized by $K$, then $N_0K$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $K \leq N_0K \leq G$.

So $K$ is maximal, unless you can find a subgroup $1 < N_0 < N$ such that $N_0$ is normalized by $K$. Can you find such examples?

Comment: Thanks @spin for the answer. What I am thinking is we can not find such $N_0$ and hence $K$ is maximal. But I don't have any proof for this. Could you give some hints. Thanks!

Comment: It is not always true. Consider e.g. semidirect products $N \rtimes \langle \theta \rangle$ with $N$ and $\theta \in Aut(N)$ suitably chosen.